# Which temperature is more precise - Fahrenheit or Celsius?

Tags: temperature

The Celsius scale has 100 degrees between BP and FP of water;  there are 180 Fahrenheit degrees between the same points. Doesn't that make Fahrenheit a more precise scale? If so, then why is it always taught in Intro Chem that Celsius is a more accurate scale and was developed with more meticulous methods? Is it maybe that Celsius is more accurate even as Fahrenheit is more precise?

Comment: This is the common nonsense you will find on the web that Fahrenheit is more precise than Celsius because it has smaller divisions than Celsius between two points. Don't trust the web especially (quora, SE, Wikipedia etc.) and random people.

Comment: Precision refers to the *measurement* and is expressed using *significant figures*, and has nothing to do with the units or choice of scales as long as margins for errors reported correctly. See [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_and_precision) for further illustration.

Comment: @theorist I have also heard the strength of imperial-units-based bolts/nuts is higher than for equivalent size metric ones. If it is true, than not because of units.

Comment: @Poutnik   There are different grading categories for metric and Imperial fasteners, but I wouldn't say one type of fastener is broadly stronger than the other. Do you have a reference for that?  I'd be curious to read it.  Imperial sizes may be available in a wider range of grading categories, though I'm not sure.  E.g.:

https://www.americanfastener.com/astm-sae-and-iso-grade-markings-for-steel-fasteners/

vs.

https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/steel-bolts-metric-grades-d_1428.html

Comment: @theorist No ref. just heard. But it may be just a prejudice, or perhaps slighly different geometry of the technical specifications, or accidental material advantage. I am not experienced here. :-)

Comment: "taught in Intro Chem that Celsius is a more accurate scale" the statement is true (the *definition* of Celsius scale is more exact), but you will hardly ever do a chemical experiment where the difference is important. We use Celsius because it is solidly linked to Kelvins, which is an *absolute* scale, that is you can properly do math with it.

Comment: @Karl  The current F scale definition is not less exact than C scale definition, as the former is defined by the latter  ( $\pu{0^{\circ} C} = \pu{32^{\circ} F},  \pu{100^{\circ} C}  = \pu{212^{\circ} F}$ ) ( saying that, I am a European metric guy, laughing at imperial units ).

Comment: As an aside, I wonder why these extra digits are necessary. 90-something percent of the time weather is reported - they quote the temperature within a 5-10 degree span. "In the 90s". Precision, my arse.

Comment: Reported as opinion-based :P

Answer (score 1):

### Celsius.

The preciseness of the scales are the same. Numbers are numbers. However, upon comparing the methods for obtaining the values, a judgement can be made.

Fahrenheit was initially set to zero with the eutectic temperature of a solution of a brine, a mixture of water and ammonium chloride in which water ice forms and is present. The secondary point, by which the scale was defined, was the body temperature of a human.

So, one scale was defined as the temperature water freezes and boils, the other defined in ice with smelling salt and then between the cheeks of the operator.

The historical fact that Fahrenheit has been retrofitted to be 180 degrees between boiling and freezing of water is a testament to which is more apt. Celsius.

Comment: I downvoted, for a quibble over presentation rather than content. The large bold **Celsius** heading at the top is, IMO, pretty misleading for two reasons. (1) If the Fahrenheit scale has ben redefined to match the Celsius scale, then the arguments you put forth are more of a historical quirk rather than a real modern consideration. The former is less relevant to users nowadays than the latter. (2) Given that that's the case, if a single-word summary were to be provided, then surely that should be *Neither* since precision is not defined by a scale but rather the measurement.

Comment: I'd almost certainly upvote instead if these nuances were made more clear. But, well, that's just my opinion!

Comment: @orthocresol If you want to downvote over quibbles then I'll leave you to it, you have a busy day ahead of you here on Chemistry! ;-) I do disagree with your quibble; IF the Fahrenheit scale is by definition a linear transformation of the Celsius scale - then the comparison is (even more) meaningless. The only way to actually decide would be to base on the definition(s) which are not a linear transformation of each other. And that race, completed some time in the past, was won by the Celsius scale. If I need to put something up my rectum to calibrate it, I'll go for the other option, thank you

Comment: Of course, Celsius himself defined his scale at having 100 degrees as the freezing point of water and 0 degrees as the boiling point! Another person, a few years later, flipped the two temperatures, to the eternal gratitude of those of us who have had to teach introductory chemistry courses!

Comment: Punch line of an old joke: “Rectum? It near killed ‘em!” ;-)

Comment: @StianYttervik I agree with you on all factual points, especially it being (even more) meaningless. I just think that *that* should be the very first point that's being made: the fact that it's meaningless, because (1) precision is a property of a measurement, which you wrote as "numbers are numbers"; and (2) F is nowadays defined as a linear shift of C. (3) Only after these considerations, does the historical definition of F and C come into play. The heading skips past 1 and 2, leading to what I perceived as an undue emphasis on 3. I'll leave it there, though; I'm happy to agree to disagree.

Comment: Can you check that last sentence? Who is apt to what?

Comment: @Karl Celsius is more apt (at measuring temperature.)

Answer (score 1):

Accuracy and precision are determined by the quality of the measurement, not the units used. The units themselves don't limit accuracy or precision, since the measurement can be expressed to whatever number of significant figures are needed, e.g., $\pu{35.4848923 ^{\circ}C}$.

As another example, grams are not more accurate or precise than kilograms. If you had a measurement where the uncertainty was in the thousandths of grams, you would express it as, e.g., $\pu{34.308 g}$. In kilograms, that same measurement would be expressed, with the same uncertainty, as $\pu{0.034308 kg}$.

On the other hand, if you were limited to only expressing temperature in *integers* then, yes, you could express temperature more precisely in Farenheit than in Celsius, because the former's integer divisions are smaller. You might see this limitation on the TV news, if the weather reporters have decided that it's cleaner to express temperature to the nearest integer. But that's an external, artificial limitation, not a limitation in the scales themselves.